# Passing JSON to Controller and save changes into database

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

Currently I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC project. I want to implement in-line editing. Therefore tha plan is to pass the data in a JSON format to the controller and save it. Problem is, I am unable to do so.

My Controller: DenoProfileController

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Update(DenoProfile denoprofile)
        {
            DenoProfile emp = db.DenoProfile.Single(em => em.DenoProfileID == denoprofile.DenoProfileID);
            emp.NetworkNumber = denoprofile.NetworkNumber;            
            db.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("IndexDenoProfile", new { id = 0 });
        }
```

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<CRUD_Profile_Creation.Models.ProfileCreationContext>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "DenoProfile";
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.edit-mode').hide();
        $('.edit-user, .cancel-user').on('click', function () {
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
        });
        $('.save-user').on('click', function () {
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            var NetworkNumber = tr.find("#NetworkNumber").html();            
           
            //Creating Employee JSON object
            var EmployeeModel =
            {
                "NetworkNumber": NetworkNumber,                
            };

            console.log(EmployeeModel.value);
            //Posting Employee object to controller's Update action method
            $.ajax({
                url: "DenoProfile/Update",
                data: JSON.stringify(EmployeeModel),
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    tr.find('.edit-mode, .display-mode').toggle();
                    alert('Record updated Successfully!!');
                }               
            });

        });

        $('.edit-user').on('click', function () {
            var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
            var NetworkNumber = tr.find("#NetworkNumber").html();
         
            tr.find("#lblNetworkNumber").text(NetworkNumber);           
        });
    })
</script>


<div class="container-fluid" align="center" justify-content="center" style="background-color:white;">
    <h1>List of Clients</h1>

    <a class="btn btn-success" asp-area="" asp-controller="DenoProfile" asp-action="AddDenoProfile">Profile Creation</a>
   
    <br />
    <br />

    <table class="table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr align="center" justify-content="center">
                <th>
                    Deno Profile ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Network Number
                </th>               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<CRUD_Profile_Creation.Models.DenoProfile>)ViewBag.DenoProfile)
            {

                <tr align="center" justify-content="center">
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DenoProfileID)                                           
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="display-mode" id="lblNetworkNumber">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NetworkNumber)
                        </div>
                        <div class="edit-mode">
                            <input type="text" id="NetworkNumber" value="@item.NetworkNumber" class="edit-mode" />
                        </div>                       
                    </td>
                    
                    <td>
                        <button class="edit-user display-mode">Edit</button>
                        <button class="save-user edit-mode">Save</button>
                        <button class="cancel-user edit-mode">Cancel</button>                        
                        <button class="btn btn-danger"> @Html.ActionLink("Delete Deno Profile", "DeleteDenoProfile", new { id = item.DenoProfileID })</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

</div>
```

Thank you to anyone who can answer or comment my post!

I think I might pass the wrong value into the function. But i am not so sure. This is also my first time trying to pass JSON or anything ajax. If you guys want to leave some tips for me down below, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Illyiana Yusof, `I am unable to do so` do you mean you cannot receive value for parameter `denoprofile`？

Comment: @Rena yes, it wont go into the function and therefore would not save the changes I have made.

Comment: Hi @Illyiana Yusof, what if you add the `[FromBody]` attribute in the action like:`public ActionResult Update([FromBody]DenoProfile denoprofile)`?

Comment: @Rena hm it didnt work for me.

Comment: Hi @Illyiana Yusof,， still not hitting the endpoint? Could you pls F12 in the browser and check the Console panel if any error display here? Also, could you pls share your `DenoProfile` model and how is your `NetworkNumber` value. Besides, pls remove `console.log(EmployeeModel.value);` this line. there is no such `.value` in your EmployeeModel variable.

Comment: @Rena Okie, so the error message is `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()` . As for my model, it is very simple. I'll put in the question above

Comment: Hi @Illyiana Yusof, 500 means your server side makes error. Could you pls check the Output panel in visual studio if any detailed exception here? And did you put the breakpoint to your endpoint Update action? Can the request go into this action?

Comment: @Rena hmm, no message/error in the output panel. the request, i dont think its entering into the function.

Comment: Hi @Illyiana Yusof, `i dont think its entering into the function.` hmmm,ok. Could you pls F12 in the browser and then refresh your page then click the `save-user` button, then  check the Network panel what is the request url, does it `DenoProfile/Update`?

Comment: @Rena hi, this is the request url 'https://localhost:44316/DenoProfile/Update' im pretty sure theres something wrong somewhere

Comment: Try putting the breakpoint in the constructor of the controller, and then step or resume from there.

Comment: Hi @Illyiana Yusof, really suggest you can put the breakpoint to your endpoint `Update` action to check which line makes error.

Comment: Hi @DavidTansey yup thank you. i did that and solved the exception by using `SingleOrDefault` instead of `Single`.

Comment: @Rena as per my comment above, i did that and the json was all good. Problem im getting now is that it says `emp` is null. Hmm

Comment: Hi @Illyiana Yusof, ,`emp` is the data you get from the database. You need firstly check if `denoprofile.DenoProfileID` contains value or not, then check if the database contains the same value with `denoprofile.DenoProfileID`.

Comment: Your `EmployeeModel` in the javascript does not have a property called `DenoProfileID` so why are you expecting a value to show up for `DenoProfileID` in the controller action?

Comment: @DavidTansey oh wow, thank you for that! mustve overlooked. unfortunately, after initiliazing it, it is still empty. checked the json data, and it's not empty when being passed down.